# How to express the solution in exponential form and plot on the complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers

> So the equation is
> $$\frac{z^4}{i^{15}+i^{80}}=-1$$

I`ve tried to solve it by this way $$z^4+iz^4=-2$$ => $$(1+i)z^4=-2$$ then I multiplied both sides by $$(1+i) => z^4=-1+i$$
From this I have $$\sqrt{2}e^{i(3\pi/4)} = z^4.$$

Then I got $$(2)^\frac{1}{8}e^i\frac{3\pi}{16}$$

which means that the roots is $$(2)^{\frac{1}{8}e^{i2k}\frac{pi}{4}+\frac{3pi}{16}}$$
How I can express the solution in exponential form and plot on the complex plane

Comment: You already have the roots in exponential form , just run through $k=-2,-1,0$ and $1$ and that should be it.

Comment: @Quippy can u give more details please